# python replace function with integer column replaced by a range a corresponding column of 10 year integer ranges

Tags: python, replace

wondering if anyone could help me with this problem I am working on... I am having trouble a column with age integers to a corresponding column of 10 year age ranges. please help!!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAHW0.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please write the data in the body of your question not an image. Please show what you have tried so your question doesn't get closed

Answer (score 1):

This is covered at length in [pandas documentation.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html)